# using sudo with mercurial and ssh authentication

Tags: mercurial, ssh, debian, sudo

How do i run
`ssh-add key

sudo hg clone hg@bitbucket.org/etc/etc`

but use my ssh keys and not the superusers.

Hey everyone, when i use sudo with for example, sudo hg clone hg@bitbucket.org/etc/etc after i have added a key to my user account it doesnt work. I remember this is because the sudo is ran as the superuser but that user cannot have keys added to it. I remember setting some directive (im using debian) that allowed me to run that command as sudo, but still have my ssh keys taken from my normal user account but i didnt make a note of it at the time. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to run hg under sudo?

Comment: i thought for the same reason everyone needs to run sudo, i dont want to give write permissions to my user account. I also found what i was looking for. env_keep=SSH_AUTH_SOCK added to your defaults in visudo allows sudo to use the SSH authentication from the account running sudo and also allows that cmd to use the privilege escalation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer by Ry4an pointed me in the right direction but I found that with the current version (1.6.4) of Hg at least, you need to put `--ssh` (or the equivalent `-e`) *after* the hg command.

e.g.

```
hg clone -e 'ssh -i /path/to/key' ssh://user@host/path
```

Answer (score 3):

I see you found a way to have the sudo user chain off to your main user's key, but rather than using ssh-agent for something like that you're more secure explicitly specifying the key:

```
sudo hg --ssh '/usr/bin/ssh -i /path/to/private.key' clone hg@bitbucket.org/etc/etc
```

Comment: ooh thats nice. Wont have to modify the sudoers file now. Thanks!

Comment: Does not work for me, error is displayed: 
 hg: option --ssh not recognized